# Extracting data from infotable while also fill in for missing values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this .txt file which is formatted like XML but the problems are that the website it was retrieved from warns me this is an invalid XML format. Through some parsing I managed to get my information in these bite sized little chunks using infoTable as a reference.

```html
  <infoTable>

    <nameOfIssuer>COMPANYONE</nameOfIssuer>

    <titleOfClass>SHS CLASS -A -</titleOfClass>

    <cusip>00000</cusip>

    <value>21944</value>

    <shrsOrPrnAmt>

      <sshPrnamt>3060500</sshPrnamt>

      <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>

    </shrsOrPrnAmt>

    <investmentDiscretion>SOLE</investmentDiscretion>

    <votingAuthority>

      <Sole>3060500</Sole>

      <Shared>0</Shared>

      <None>0</None>

    </votingAuthority>

  </infoTable>

  <infoTable>

    <nameOfIssuer>COMPANYTWO</nameOfIssuer>

    <titleOfClass>COM</titleOfClass>

    <cusip>00001</cusip>

    <value>67822</value>

    <shrsOrPrnAmt>

      <sshPrnamt>1898717</sshPrnamt>

      <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>

    </shrsOrPrnAmt>

    <investmentDiscretion>SOLE</investmentDiscretion>

    <votingAuthority>

      <Sole>1898717</Sole>

      <Shared>0</Shared>

      <None>0</None>

    </votingAuthority>

  </infoTable>

  <infoTable>

    <nameOfIssuer>COMPANYTHREE</nameOfIssuer>

    <titleOfClass>CL B NEW</titleOfClass>

    <cusip>00002</cusip>

    <value>10462145</value>

    <shrsOrPrnAmt>

      <sshPrnamt>52078974</sshPrnamt>

      <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>

    </shrsOrPrnAmt>

    <investmentDiscretion>SOLE</investmentDiscretion>

    <votingAuthority>

      <Sole>52078974</Sole>

      <Shared>0</Shared>

      <None>0</None>

    </votingAuthority>

  </infoTable>
```

My problem is that I do not know how to properly extract the values from the tags. I have tried something along like this

`soup = BeautifulSoup("myData")
soup = find_all("nameOfIssuer")[0].readContent()`

but that leads me with out of bounds error. Also the problem is that while this .txt does not show it, the data I obtained it from has missing columns that I want to fill in as NaN. So ideally I am trying to get my data in tsv format

```
NameofIssuer TitleofClass cusip value   shrsPrnamt  shrsPrnamtType  putcall  investmentDescrestion  othermanager   vaSole  vaShared   vaNone
COMPANYONE   CL B NEW     00000 21944   3060500     SH              NaN      SOLE                   NaN            3060500 0          0
COMPANYTWO   COM          00001 67822   1898717     SH              NaN      SOLE                   NaN            1898717 0          0
```

EDIT: At the suggestion of @RomanPerekhrest I have included an extra XML file which shows the `othermanager` and `putcall` tags

```html
<ns1:infoTable>
        <ns1:nameOfIssuer>COMPANYFOUR</ns1:nameOfIssuer>
        <ns1:titleOfClass>COM</ns1:titleOfClass>
        <ns1:cusip>00004</ns1:cusip>
        <ns1:value>67</ns1:value>
        <ns1:shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <ns1:sshPrnamt>36100</ns1:sshPrnamt>
            <ns1:sshPrnamtType>SH</ns1:sshPrnamtType>
        </ns1:shrsOrPrnAmt>
        <ns1:putCall>Call</ns1:putCall>
        <ns1:investmentDiscretion>DFND</ns1:investmentDiscretion>
        <ns1:otherManager>01, 02</ns1:otherManager>
        <ns1:votingAuthority>
            <ns1:Sole>36100</ns1:Sole>
            <ns1:Shared>0</ns1:Shared>
            <ns1:None>0</ns1:None>
        </ns1:votingAuthority>
    </ns1:infoTable>
    <ns1:infoTable>
        <ns1:nameOfIssuer>COMPANYFIVE</ns1:nameOfIssuer>
        <ns1:titleOfClass>SPONSORED ADS A</ns1:titleOfClass>
        <ns1:cusip>00005</ns1:cusip>
        <ns1:value>2695</ns1:value>
        <ns1:shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <ns1:sshPrnamt>339367</ns1:sshPrnamt>
            <ns1:sshPrnamtType>SH</ns1:sshPrnamtType>
        </ns1:shrsOrPrnAmt>
        <ns1:investmentDiscretion>DFND</ns1:investmentDiscretion>
        <ns1:otherManager>01, 02</ns1:otherManager>
        <ns1:votingAuthority>
            <ns1:Sole>339367</ns1:Sole>
            <ns1:Shared>0</ns1:Shared>
            <ns1:None>0</ns1:None>
        </ns1:votingAuthority>
    </ns1:infoTable>
```

Comment: `othermanager` and `putcall` tags are not present in your xml, why they should be in the result?

Comment: Now that I think about this is a really bad example file, but this was just one of the samples that I was working with. Other files i noticed have the othermanager and putcall tags

Comment: that means that you need whether to post another input xml OR edit your expected result - to correlate input and output

Comment: Hello, I have just included another example XML to show the two missing tags

Comment: how large is the input text file?

Comment: Averages between 12-15mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `data` is concatenating the strings found in question ([link](https://pastebin.com/qdVNWQHJ) - too long to paste it here):

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

cols = ['nameOfIssuer', 'titleOfClass', 'cusip', 'value', 'sshPrnamt', 'sshPrnamtType', 'putCall', 'investmentDiscretion', 'otherManager', 'Sole', 'Shared', 'None']

data = []
for info_table in soup.find_all(['ns1:infotable', 'infotable']):
    row = []
    for col in cols:
        d = info_table.find([col.lower(), 'ns1:' + col.lower()])

        row.append(d.text.strip() if d else 'NaN')
    data.append(row)

headers = ['NameofIssuer', 'TitleofClass', 'cusip', 'value', 'shrsPrnamt', 'shrsPrnamtType', 'putcall', 'investmentDescrestion', 'othermanager', 'vaSole', 'vaShared', 'vaNone']
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(headers)
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

Writes `data.csv`:

```
NameofIssuer,TitleofClass,cusip,value,shrsPrnamt,shrsPrnamtType,putcall,investmentDescrestion,othermanager,vaSole,vaShared,vaNone
COMPANYFOUR,COM,00004,67,36100,SH,Call,DFND,"01, 02",36100,0,0
COMPANYFIVE,SPONSORED ADS A,00005,2695,339367,SH,NaN,DFND,"01, 02",339367,0,0
COMPANYONE,SHS CLASS -A -,00000,21944,3060500,SH,NaN,SOLE,NaN,3060500,0,0
COMPANYTWO,COM,00001,67822,1898717,SH,NaN,SOLE,NaN,1898717,0,0
COMPANYTHREE,CL B NEW,00002,10462145,52078974,SH,NaN,SOLE,NaN,52078974,0,0
```

In LibreOffice it looks:

[image]

Comment: Would this process work the same if I just had a variable open the specified .txt files I want to parse through? Instead of just saving everything in a string?

Comment: @onbu I presume yes. Try to load the data e.g. `soup = BeautifulSoup(open('yourfile.txt', 'r').read(), 'lxml')`.

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution with `lxml.etree`, `OrderdedDict` and `pandas` library:

We need to fix a malformed XML content at first: the main idea is to add `root` tag with xml *namespace* (`ns1`). For demo purpose the input *xml* (taken from the question as is) is parsed as a string with further required modification.

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

xml_content = '<root xmlns:ns1="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">{}</root>'\
    .format(open('base.xml').read())
doc = etree.fromstring(xml_content)
ns = {'ns1': 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'}
records = []

for block in doc.findall('ns1:infoTable', namespaces=ns):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for el in block.getchildren():
        el_tag = el.tag.replace("{{{}}}".format(ns['ns1']), '')
        inner_childs = el.getchildren()
        if inner_childs:    # if element has child nodes
            prefix = 'va' if el_tag == 'votingAuthority' else ''
            d.update({prefix + child.tag.replace("{{{}}}".format(ns['ns1']), ''): child.text
                      for child in inner_childs})
        else:
            d[el_tag] = el.text
    records.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df.to_string(index=False, justify=True))
```

The output:

```
nameOfIssuer     titleOfClass  cusip value sshPrnamt sshPrnamtType putCall investmentDiscretion otherManager  vaSole vaShared vaNone
 COMPANYFOUR              COM  00004    67     36100            SH    Call                 DFND       01, 02   36100        0      0
 COMPANYFIVE  SPONSORED ADS A  00005  2695    339367            SH     NaN                 DFND       01, 02  339367        0      0
```

To save the result into csv file with desired separator - use `df.to_csv()` routine:

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='output.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```